# Detect punctuation and echo it separately

Tags: php, punctuation

I want to detect punctuation (!@#$%^&*()?<>"';:}{][) wherever in a string (front or behind the string)...

```
$string = "'Hello!'";
$anotherstring = "Hi";
```

I want it to record the punctuation in `$string` and echo it with `$anotherstring`...

Hello

'Hi!'

Actually I am making a spell checker and the problem is that it checks the string with the punctuation.. I want to check it without the punctuation and echo the before punctuation before the suggestions and the after punctuation after the suggestions...

Comment: Spell checker or grammar checker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe a dirty trick :)

```
$anotherstring = preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $anotherstring, $string);
```

EDIT: You can remove the digits if you don't need them

Comment: will it work if punctuation is there on both the sides?? @Mirko Akkov

Comment: But what if I want to  echo the before punctuation before the suggestions and the after punctuation after the suggestions... @Mirko Akkov

Comment: You can do it like so: $cleanstring = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $string);

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php

You can split based on tokens such as spaces and symbols.